# Responsive design that manipulates multi-column content

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, multiple-columns

I would like to implement a UI with 1 or 2 columns depending on screen/device width. I'm using Ajax to load data into these two columns and append it according to those item heights so both columns take approx. the same amount of vertical space.

Everything's ok if user keeps their browser window size the same at all time, because initial loading will either fill 1 or 2 columns. But the problem arises when the user resizes their window I have to consolidate all content accordingly:

- smaller size hides column 2 and all it's items should be inserted into columns 1 in correct order
- larger size displays both columns and takes some content from column 1 and puts it into column 2

I can use Javascript to do this, but I was wondering whether it's possible to do the same in CSS only way?

An example of this is Google+ that works with 1..3 columns depending on content width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I came up with a solution of my own

### It is possible using CSS only but maybe not feasible

Feasible in terms of resource consumption. When adding items on the page, always put **all** of them in column 1 adding an additional CSS class to those that you also position in column 2.

Responsive media queries will then either:

1. Hide column 2 and show those additional items in column 1 (based on CSS class).
2. Show column 2 and hide items with appropriate CSS class in column 1

That's the only way to avoid Javascript processing when user resizes their browser window.

### The problem

The only problem there is to this functionality is when you display lots of items, because your DOM will have on average 50% more nodes as approximately half of those items will be duplicated across the page (even though only one copy of those duplicates will be shown at a time).